# How create modalVC with navBar and custom size?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I need to create custom modalVC with custom size ( ex: `CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)` and coordinates). ModalVC may be NOT like popover( popover has rounded corners).

There will be navigation bar with item "Done" for dismiss this modalVC.

VC will create for UIButton pressing in other VC.

There is my code(created of other code, only popover present):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        showModalVC()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func showModalVC() {
        let modalVC = CustomModalViewController()
        modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        if let modal = modalVC.popoverPresentationController {
            modal.delegate = self
            modal.sourceView = self.view
        }
        self.present(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class CustomModalViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                                           height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/3)
    }
}
```

> P.S: I know how to do this like PopOver, but not like custom modal.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please, provide us with your code

Comment: You might be a bit more specific in your end result but I believe what you are looking for is "adding a child view controller". Please check this link a bit: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as! YourViewController
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC)
navController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 400)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: That's good, but maybe you can add info about how set modalVC to bottom of screen and set it width = screen width?